# How to find mac user name and password

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

HI I want to create an ios application in visual studio using xamarin.
But After creating project it is asking us to connect to mac.

Which Credentials it is asking for and how to find it.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making use of [***Xamarin.VS Build Host Application***](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/introduction_to_xamarin_ios_for_visual_studio/#Visual_Studio_Features_for_iOS)

Refer :

- https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/xamarin-mac-agent/#Windows_Setup
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt299001.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#AddiOS

Answer (score 0):

Are you tired of getting the below error on pairing to mac from a windows system

> Invalid credentials. Please try again

Never thought that pairing to mac from a windows system would be this simple!

Username : **Name** displayed while you log-in to open your Mac system
Password : **Password** you enter to log-in for the above username displayed

Still not sure?

1. Choose System Preferences from the Apple menu, then click Users & Groups.
2. You can see user name as **Current User** Reference : https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202860

To know the Mac IP address, check **manually add a mac** from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/#manually-add-a-mac

Detailed reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/